# how to configure vosao cms for GAE in netbeans

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

I am trying to `configure http://www.vosao.org/`  in `netbeans` for `GAE` there is no any tutorial or documentation for this. Can you please say how we can configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, if you don't want to change backend code and spare yourself the setup effort of compiling sources, just use Eclipse (or maybe even Netbeans) to run a local server and deploy to GAE, you can create and empty GAE project and just overwrite the `war` folder in there with Vosao.

Make sure to uncheck sample code and GWT to make your life even easier: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no answer yet, I will tell you that there is a tutorial about deploying Vosao from Eclipse right here: 
http://www.rarejava.com/blog/2011/07/deploying-vosao-from-eclipse